# How to write SQL statement to select for data broken up for each month of the year?

Tags: sql

I am looking for a way to write an SQL statement that selects data for each month of the year, separately.

In the SQL statement below, I am trying to count the number of instances in the TOTAL_PRECIP_IN and TOTAL_SNOWFALL_IN columns when either column is greater than 0. In my data table, I have information for those two columns ("TOTAL_PRECIP_IN" and "TOTAL_SNOWFALL_IN") for each day of the year (365 total entries).

I want to break up my data by each calendar month, but am not sure of the best way to do this. In the statement below, I am using a UNION statement to break up the months of January and February. If I keep using UNION statements for the remaining months of the year, I can get the answer I am looking for. However, using 11 different UNION statements cannot be the optimal solution.

**Can anyone give me a suggestion how I can edit my SQL statement to measure from the first day of the month, to the last day of the month for every month of the year?**

````
select monthname(OBSERVATION_DATE) as "Month", sum(case when TOTAL_PRECIP_IN or TOTAL_SNOWFALL_IN > 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS "Days of Rain" from EMP_BASIC
    where OBSERVATION_DATE between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31'
    and CITY = 'Olympia'
    group by "Month"
UNION
select monthname(OBSERVATION_DATE) as "Month", sum(case when TOTAL_PRECIP_IN or TOTAL_SNOWFALL_IN > 0 then 1 else 0 end) from EMP_BASIC
    where OBSERVATION_DATE between '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-28'
    and CITY = 'Olympia'
    group by "Month"```
````

Comment: please tag only single database. Do not spam the tag

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using (and it can't be Postgres as there it does not have a `monthname()` function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table structure is too unclear to tell you the exact query you will need. But a general easy idea is to build the sum of your value and then group by monthname and/or by month. Sice you wrote you only want sum values greater 0, you can just put this condition in the where clause. So your query will be something like this:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(yourdate) AS month, 
MONTH(yourdate) AS monthnr, 
SUM(yourvalue) AS yoursum
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourvalue > 0
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(yourdate), MONTH(yourdate)
ORDER BY MONTH(yourdate);
```

I created an example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f692ec3627822fbe5cd11f68847e0179)

You might need to modify this general construct for your concrete purpose (maybe take care of different years, of NULL values etc.). And note this is an example for a MYSQL DB because you wrote about MONTHNAME() which is in most cases used in MYSQL databases. If you are using another DB type, maybe you need to do some modifications. To make sure that answers match your DB type, tag it in your question, please.